# Running Hadoop Examples

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am pretty new to Java so this may actually be a Java question too but so let's say I want to learn Apache Crunch, so I read their tutorial and there is an example there:
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/10/introducing-crunch/

Now I want to run this example. What do I need?
I have installed a local hadoop, that one I have. 
So whats next? we should create a Java project with that package name it has just that one class?

Answer (score 1):

If your hadoop is correctly installed use :

```
{path to hadoop install}/bin/hadoop jar {path to hadoop install}/lib/hadoop-exemple.jar wordcount {input file} {output file}
```

You should put some files on your hdfs first using :

`hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal {file to copy} {path on hdfs}`

Hope that helps

Comment: yep thanks, but one step before that is to create that "jar" file. So I was wondering how to go from that code example posted to have a JAR file for it.

Comment: That jar is not in your hadoop install ? in hadoop-x-x/lib maybe ?